# How to change boolean into string in a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
    protected:
        bool isMammal;
        bool isCarnivorous;    
    public:
        Animal(bool, bool, string);
        bool getIsMammal(){return isMammal;}
        bool getIsCarnivorous(){return isCarnivorous;}
};

Animal::Animal(bool isMammal, bool isCarnivorous){
    this -> isMammal = isMammal;
    this -> isCarnivorous = isCarnivorous;
}

int main(){    
    Animal Dog(true, true);
    cout << "A dog is " << Dog.getIsCarnivorous() << ", and is a " << Dog.getIsMammal();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose I have this code. I am expecting to have a string output like
`A dog is carnivorous, and is a mammal`.
But instead, I got this `A dog is a 1, and is a 1`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are printing a `bool` which is printed as 1 if it's true and 0 if it's false. What should be printed of your animal is a cow? You need to write the code that decides what to print

Comment: You are printing a `bool`. a `bool` is something with the value of either `1` or `0`. Why do you expect it to print a string `"mammal"`?

Comment: How about:  `cout << "A dog is " << (Dog.getIsCarnivorous() ? "carnivorous" : "not carnivorous) << ", and is a " << (Dog.getIsMammal() ? "mammal" : "not mammal";`

Comment: You could use a ternary operator:  `cout << ((const char *) (bool_variable ? "true" : "false"));`

Comment: Even if it worked that way, you should expect "A dog is isCarnivorous", which isn't any better. And, worse, "A cow is isCarnivorous" as well. You are confusing variable identifier and variable value and data formatting.

Comment: An `if` statement?

Comment: There is a stream manipulator [`std::boolapha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) to control how `bool` is streamed. Or you can manually set the flag with [`cout.setf(std::ios_base::boolalpha)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf).

Comment: @Jabberwocky I want to convert `true` (boolean) to `mammal` (string). Thank you, it solved though.

Comment: @Eljay Yes it does work, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a conditional operator:

```
cout << "A dog is " << (Dog.GetIsCarnivorous() ? "" : "not ") << "carnivorous, and is " << (Dog.getIsMammal() ? "" : "not ") << "a mammal.";
```

Comment: To make it more readable, you could always extract all the logic to a separate statement before doing the `cout`. Like `string a = ....` followed by `cout << ....`

Comment: I see, thank you. I though I cannot use ternary operator in one line within `cout`. I got an error before because I missed the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

```
string getIsCarnivorous() { return string(isMammal ? "carnivorous" : "not carnivorous"); }
string getIsMammal() { return string(isMammal ? "a mammal" : "not a mammal"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operstor

```
string getIsMammal( ){
        return (isMammal?"is mammal":"");
   }
```

And the same for the other function.

In any case it does not seem the best programming to return a string as you should separate data from its view. I would keep the Boolean return and make the view logic out of the class.

```
cout << "a dog " << dog.getIsMammal()?"is mammal":"" << endl;
```